# Absolutely continuous measure

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I need some help for solving a problem. The problem is:
Let $\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}$ be a absolutely continuous measure w.r.t. ${\mathbb{P}}$ and such that there exists $c\geq1$ satisfying $\widetilde{\mathbb{dP}}/\mathbb{dP}\leq c$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s: Prove that there exists  $\alpha \in$ (0; 1] and a probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ such that 
$\mathbb{P}=\alpha\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}+(1-\alpha)\mathbb{Q}$.
I have tried to solve it by writing the differential equation: $\mathbb{dP}=\alpha d\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}+(1-\alpha)\mathbb{dQ}$.
I know also that $\mathbb{dP/dQ}=Y$ ; $Y$ being the Radon-Nikodym density, but I don't find the reasoning to prove the equation. 
Could you please help me?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if these is enough, but as far as I understand, define $Q(A) = \frac{P(A)-\alpha \widetilde{P}(A)}{1-\alpha}$. (for the case $\alpha \neq 1$.)

Now it should be shown that this defines probability measure. Substitute $$\widetilde{P}(A) = \int_{A}\frac{d\widetilde{P}}{dP}dP$$.
It is obvious that $P(A)-\alpha \widetilde{P}(A)=P(A)-\alpha\int_{A}\frac{d\widetilde{P}}{dP}dP \geq P(A)(1-\alpha c)$.
Take $\alpha < \frac{1}{c}$. This will provide you the non-negativity.

Next let's take the whole $\Omega$. We will have $Q(\Omega) = \frac{P(\Omega)-\alpha \widetilde{P}(\Omega)}{1-\alpha} = 1$.
This provides that it's maximum value is 1. 
The fact that it is countably additive comes straitforward with countable additivity of $P$ and $\widetilde{P}$.

It seems to me $\alpha=1 $ is necessary only when $P(A)=\widetilde{P}(A)$ for every A. (But maybe I'm wrong).